# Is everything in Westworld made of the "white stuff"?

Tags: westworld-2016

In the opening titles of the *Westworld* TV series, we see various things being constructed using some sort of white "thread".

This is mostly people (hosts) and animals, but it also looks like a piano is being built this way.

[image: Westworld opening credits, Piano creation] [image: Westworld opening credits, Piano]
<sub><sub>***Click images to embiggen.***</sub></sub>

Does this mean that all the buildings, clothes, weapons and everything else is made of this material? If so, why? Surely it would have been a lot less trouble to put a real piano in the saloon, or to build a house using real wood, for instance?

Comment: Watching the credits I can't see any evidence the "white stuff" is used to make the piano. Just looks like there is a piano there.

Comment: On the video clip you helpfully added, between 0:08 and 0:12, it appears to be attaching what look like piano strings, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: Aye does look like that (missed it the first time), added image in.

Comment: Just to nitpick: "Surely it would have been a lot less trouble to put a real piano in the saloon" Not that sure. The white stuff machine is a hardcore version of our 3D printers and some (many?) people say 3D printers are a revolution and we would rather print objects at home rather than going to a shop in a near future. Also, the Delos company in season 1 (I didn't see season 2 yet) emphasizes its control over the environment of the park. They may have created some elements of the park like the piano if they considered it important.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### No.

We know for a fact that the oldest/first generations of hosts are constructed of metal and feature a much more robotic interior than the later, "white stuff" fabricated, hosts.

[image]

As for buildings, there is no evidence to support the idea that the buildings are made from the "white stuff", and there is actually evidence of the opposite; as seen through flashbacks, many of the buildings that stand have been around since the initial opening of the park (specifically in Sweetwater), long before the 'white stuff' technology was utilized.